# How can i dynamically assign filename with -w option in tcpdump.sh on freebsd?

Tags: perl, bash, freebsd

How can i dynamically assign filename with -w option here ?

I am working on freebsd. I want to dynamically assign filename to the file created using -w option in this perl script. I have been using following method but to no avail.

```
$name = `date`;
system ("nstcpdump.sh -C 1 -w $name");
```

Can someone help me with this ?

Comment: variable must be enclosed between double quotes to avoid shell expansion `"$name"`

Comment: 'nstcpdump.sh -C 1 -w "$name"' and "nstcpdump.sh -C 1 -w \"$name\"" should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the multiple argument form of system:

```
system 'nstcpdump.sh', '-C', '1', '-w', $name;
```

you also may want to remove the spaces from the date string:

```
( my $name = `date` ) =~ s/\s/_/g;
```